# How to add a q value (adjusted p-value) to a modelsummary table after pooling the results of a multinomial model over multiple imputed datasets

Tags: r, modelsummary, q-value

I am using `modelsummary` to display the results of several multinomial models, each pooled over 5 datasets using the `mice::pool function`. It works great, but I want to add the q-value / adjusted p-value for false discovery rate.

I understand I need to create a `tidy_custom.mipo` function to add this statistic but I can't get it to work.

Below is the code to get the 'pool_univariate' list of mipo objects, which I then pass to modelsummary. It works great, I just want to add the q-value statistic.

Any idea how to do that?

Thanks a lot!

```
# list of exposures 
exposures <- c(
    Cs(exposure1,exposure2,exposure3)

## model function
models <- function(x) {
    lapply(imputed_data, function(y)
        multinom(as.formula(
            paste0(
                "outcome ~ ",
                x
            )
        ), data = y, model = TRUE)
    )
}

## run models
models_univariate <- as.list(seq(1,length(exposures))) 
models_univariate <- pblapply(exposures, models)

## pool 

pool_univariate <- as.list(seq(1,length(exposures))) 

# run pool
for(j in seq_along(exposures)) {
    pool_univariate[[j]] <- pool(models_univariate[[j]])
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is difficult to answer this question without a minimal working example. Here I give a simpler example than the original, for the linear regression context.

First, load the package and estimate a regression model:

```r
library(modelsummary)
mod <- lm(mpg ~ hp + drat + vs + am, data = mtcars)
```

Second, since we want to summarize a model of class `lm`, we define a new method called `tidy_custom.lm`. This function takes a statistical model as input, and returns a data frame that conforms to the [`broom` package specification](https://broom.tidymodels.org/), with one column called `term` and other columns containing matching statistics. In the current example, the data frame will include three new statistics (`q.value`, `bonferroni` and `holm`). These values are computed using `R`’s `p.adjust` function, which adjusts p values for multiple comparison:

```r
tidy_custom.lm <- function(x, ...) {
  out <- broom::tidy(x)
  out$q.value <- p.adjust(out$p.value, n = 10, method = "fdr")
  out$bonferroni <- p.adjust(out$p.value, n = 10, method = "bonferroni")
  out$holm <- p.adjust(out$p.value, n = 10, method = "holm")
  return(out)
}
```

Now, we can call `modelsummary` with our `lm` model, and request the statistics:

```r
modelsummary(mod, statistic = "q.value")
```

[image]

We can also compare different p values and [label them nicely using `glue` strings](https://glue.tidyverse.org/):

```r
modelsummary(mod,
  statistic = c(
    "p = {p.value}",
    "q = {q.value}",
    "p (Bonferroni) = {bonferroni}",
    "p (Holm) = {holm}"
  )
)
```

[image]

Comment: Q-values would just be adding the fdr method to p.adjust.

Comment: Thanks! Obviously, I should have taken that extra step. The answer is updated.